# Svg output for Mathematics using htlatex or tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, svg, mathematics

A LaTeX document is to be converted to html using tex4ht or htlatex. If the .cfg file is included with

```
\Configure{html}{xml}
\Preamble{xhtml}
```

or

```
\Configure{html}{xml}
\Preamble{xhtml,png}
```

The mathematics content gets converted to png images. How can I configure it to something like

```
\Configure{html}{xml}
    \Preamble{xhtml,svg}
```

to get svg images for mathematics. I have tried

```
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
```

(I know make4ht but unfortunately I am not able to install it on windows with Miktex 2.9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Miktex packages for `tex4ht` have been updated last week, they should be fully synchronized with the current state of `tex4ht` development. If you have the updated system, it is possible to to request the SVG output for math and other picture elements using `svg` command line option, or from the configuration file, as in your code samples.

The following commands should work:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,svg"
```

or

```
make4ht filename.tex "svg"
```

If everything works correctly, you should find calls to `dvisvgm` command in the terminal output.